# Find list of common levels over a time serie

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been trying to do the following within the `dplyr` package but without success.

I need to find which levels of a certain factor column are present in every level of another factor column, in my case, it is a Year column. This could be an example dataset:

```
ID              Year       
1568            2013         
1341            2013          
1568            2014
1341            2014
1261            2014
1348            2015         
1568            2015 
1341            2015
```

So I would like a list of the ID names that are present in every year. In the above example would be:

```
"1568", "1341"
```

I have been trying with `dplyr` to first `grou_by` column `Year` and then `summarise` the data somehow, but withouth achieving it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and select the groups which has same number of unique `Year` as the complete data.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Year) == n_distinct(.$Year)) %>%
  pull(ID) %>%unique()

#[1] 1568 1341
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `intersect()` + `split()`

```
comm <- Reduce(intersect,split(df$ID,df$Year))
```

such that

```
> comm
[1] 1568 1341
```

Comment: I like the `Reduce(intersect`

Comment: @akrun thanks for liking it, but it think it might be slow if when with many rows of df due to `intersect`